# How to set working directory of cmd, at the same time as executing a program

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

I currently have a command that I thought did this:

```
START /WAIT cmd.exe /d tester test.cmd
```

Although it does not appear to work, it only changes the directory, not executing test.cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
start /wait /d tester cmd.exe "/c test.cmd"
```

Or simply:

```
start /wait /d tester test.cmd
```